# Highcharts Dashboard Page is loading slowly

Tags: javascript, php, html, postgresql, highcharts

I created a dashboard for monitoring statistics and therefore I used highcharts with php (postgres database as backend).

My problem is that I have 32 charts on one page and the page is loading very slowly (around 40secs.)

Here is my index.php code:

```
<p style="color:black; font-size:20px"> System CPU </p>
              <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <div id="cpu_workload_1"  style="width: 100%; height:300px; margin: 0 auto" class="chartjs-wrapper">
                          <?php include("php/05_cpu_workload/05_cpu_workload_1.php"); ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card-body">
                         <div id="cpu_workload_2"  style="width: 100%; height:300px; margin: 0 auto" class="chartjs-wrapper">
                              <?php include("php/05_cpu_workload/05_cpu_workload_2.php"); ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card-body">
                         <div id="cpu_workload_3"  style="width: 100%; height:300px; margin: 0 auto" class="chartjs-wrapper">
                                <?php include("php/05_cpu_workload/05_cpu_workload_3.php"); ?>
                     
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                 <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card-body">
                         <div id="cpu_workload_4"  style="width: 100%; height:300px; margin: 0 auto" class="chartjs-wrapper">
                            <?php include("php/05_cpu_workload/05_cpu_workload_4"); ?> 
            
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>




        </div>
```

and this is my php file: (one of them the other 3 looks the same, only the select query is differnt in where clause)

```
<?php
require("php/00connection.php");

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT cpuuser, cpunice, cpusystem, cpuiowait, cpusteal, cpuidle, epoch_time FROM cpu_workload WHERE host_id=1 ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();

foreach ($sql as $row) {
    $cpu_user_1[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['cpuuser']."]";
    $cpu_nice_1[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['cpunice']."]";
    $cpu_system_1[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['cpusystem']."]";
    $cpu_iowait_1[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['cpuiowait']."]";
    $cpu_steal_1[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['cpusteal']."]";
    $cpu_idle_helium[] = "[".$row['epoch_time'].",".$row['cpuidle']."]";
    
    $date_1[] = $row['epoch_time'];


}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

        var seriesCpuUser = [ <?php echo join($cpu_user_1, ',') ?> ];
        var seriesCpuNice = [ <?php echo join($cpu_nice_1, ',') ?> ];
        var seriesCpuSystem = [ <?php echo join($cpu_system_1, ',') ?> ];
        var seriesCpuIOWait = [ <?php echo join($cpu_iowait_1, ',') ?> ];
        var seriesCpuSteal = [ <?php echo join($cpu_steal_1, ',') ?> ];
        var seriesCpuIdle = [ <?php echo join($cpu_idle_helium, ',') ?> ];

        var options ={
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'cpu_workload_1',
                type: 'line',
                zoomType: 'x',
        setSize: 400
            },
            time: {
              timezoneOffset: -2*60,
            },
            title: {
                text: "server1"  
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: "Datetime"
                },
                type:'datetime',
                labels: {
            format: '{value:%Y-%m-%d}',
                }
            },
            yAxis: {    
                title: {
                    text: 'System CPU'
                }
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                enabled: true,
                inputEnabled: false,
                buttonPosition: {
                 align: 'right'
                },
                labelStyle: {
                    display: 'none'
                },

                buttons: [
                    {
                        type: 'hour',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1h'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1d'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1m'
                    },
            {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 6,
                        text: '6m'
                    },
                    {    
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1y'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }

                ]
            },
             tooltip: {
                //crosshairs: true,
                shared: true,
                valueSuffix: '%',
                xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
             },
             series: [{         
                 name: '%user',
                 data: seriesCpuUser
        }, {
            name: '%nice',
            data: seriesCpuNice
        },{
            name: '%system',
            data: seriesCpuSystem
        },{
            name: '%iowait',
            data: seriesCpuIOWait
        },{
            name: '%steal',
            data: seriesCpuSteal
        },{
            name: '%idle',
            data: seriesCpuIdle
        }

    ]
        };
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
    });
    
    
</script>
```

I think the main problem is that the html file is loaded sequentially and the charts are not created parallely. How can I make it executed in parallel and not sequentially? Because every chart is drawn after the other and not every chart at the same time.

Thanks!

Comment: 32 charts are not such a big amount, it should work fine. Are you able to reproduce this issue with sample data on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thanks for your answer! https://jsfiddle.net/mymarcelsql/3t6qd9vp/23/   I uploaded my html file with the chart containers and 1 sample php script (I have one php script for every chart, my backend contains a postgres database from where I get the data) I hope this helps!

Comment: @SebastianWędzel one php script/chart. And I think html executes sequentially the first php script waits till the chart is drawn, then executes the second php scripts wait till the seconds chart is drawn and so on...

Comment: Why don't you fetch all your data and then render all charts, when data will be fetched and ready to use?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel what do you mean? Can you give an example? Thank you very much!

Comment: mymarcelsql, I have in mind something like is done here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k6v3rowc/?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel okay do you mean I should use only a single php file with my sql queries? But how can I save the output of my sql statements into the chartData array? And how can I include the php file then in my html file? Because It is not a javascript file ? I thought I have to "<php include ...."> the php file at every container Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: mymarcelsql, sorry I don't know PHP, I am a Highcharts engineer and I think that downloading all data and storing it in the variable and then render the charts will be a better approach than your current implementation and should improve the performance.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel okay I changed the code into one single php file but its not really faster. It seems that the chart building is taking so long. Maybe I can share pictures or something like? The website takes around 35 secs. until it is fully loaded. My first part includes the sql statements and the seconds js part I save the php results in a variable and then I create the charts. The charts are printed correctly but slow

Comment: What is the format of your data?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel it is an array. for example memory_usage_data [ [time1, value1], [time2,value2] ... ] I have changed all queries and fetching all data into one single file but it is not really faster...

Comment: Have you tried to parse your data into the JSON format?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel yes but this was only possible with 1 series. On some charts I have multiple series and then my getJSON code did not work anymore. Maybe the amount of data is to much for highcharts?  500k / chart?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel sorry I meant 50-200k / chart

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention about such a big amount of data. The question is - this time to render your page which you mentioned (35 sec) does it take to download the data or download data and render the charts? Because if it takes only fetching data I am not able to help you, but in case of fetching and rendering charts maybe the using the boost module will speed up performance. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thanks for your reply. I think it is because the rendering took so long. My php part take about 10 seconds, the rest is the javascript part. I already included the <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script> and <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script> The data is fetched but then it takes so long till the charts are visible.

Comment: Have you turned animation off?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel yes something like that: Highcharts.setOptions({
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
              animation: false
          }  
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'line', ....    but it does not speed up the loading process

Comment: I am afraid that I don't have any more ideas how to speed it up... Are you able to share the URL to your app?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel of course: http://82.165.112.200/rit/ritmon_new/index.php (its the light version (the half of the charts so that I can analyse the things faster))

Comment: What are the steps to render the charts?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel 1) execute select - statements 2) fetch data from statement 3) save php results in javascript variables 4) Set Highchart Options 5) create charts with var chart_1 = new Highcharts.Chart(....)

Comment: mymarcelsql, I am not able to see the charts. Your link doesn't work. I have two other approaches which you can try to implement: 1. Datagrouping https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping 2. Lazy loading. https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/lazy-loading